# javascript validation prevent certain words

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to prevent users from entering in certain words and special characters into a text field like "and", "or", "/","\". How do I set a variable to two or more conditions, or how better should I approach this.

To start I was trying to prevent users from entering in "and" or or into the text field.

```
function watchForWords(text) {
  if (!text) {
  return true;
  }
  var isValid = (text.value != "and" || text.value != "or");
  if (!isValid) {
  text.style.backgroundColor = "#ff8";
  }
return isValid;
}
```

Comment: `var isValid = (text.value != "and" && text.value != "or");`

Comment: look at [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement.

Comment: `text.value.match(/(and|or|\/|\\)/)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options, depending on how you want to define "word." If you mean a string of text, you can use something simple, like `indexOf` to check whether one string contains another. If you literally mean word, in the space-delimited sense, you likely want a regex.

Simple:

```js
var blacklist = ["and", "or", "/", "\\"];

function validate(input) {
  for (var i = 0; i < blacklist.length; ++i) {
    if (input.indexOf(blacklist[i]) >= -1) {
      // String is present
      return false;
    }
  }
  // No blacklisted strings are present
  return true;
}

console.log("this is a clean string", validate("this is a clean string")); // true
console.log("and this is a dirty string", validate("and this is a dirty string")); // false
console.log("andthis is also dirty", validate("andthis is also dirty")); // false
```

Regex:

```js
var blacklist = ["and", "or", "/", "\\"];

function validate(input) {
  for (var i = 0; i < blacklist.length; ++i) {
    var expr = new RegExp("\\b" + blacklist[i] + "\\b");

    if (expr.exec(input)) {
      // String is present
      return false;
    }
  }
  // No blacklisted strings are present
  return true;
}

console.log("this is a clean string", validate("this is a clean string")); // true
console.log("and this is a dirty string", validate("and this is a dirty string")); // false
console.log("andthis is also dirty", validate("andthis is also dirty")); // true, note the difference from the previous because of no word sep
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var isValid = !/(\w+)?and|or|\/|\\\w+/.exec(myString)
```

isValid will be true if it doesn't contain "and" or "or" or any of the other chars you stated and false if it does contain at least one of them