# how to compare a string input field value with array of word in a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I've been trying to get a form to load custom errors if some conditions are met,
I've been able to accomplish some of the desired results but I am still yet to achieve the condition of comparing the input field value with an array of words, this is my code

```js
var blacklistU = ["and", "or", "/", "\\"];
var blacklistP = ["and", "or", "/", "\\"];
const err = "Your username and password doesn't match what we have on file. Try signing in again or choose <a href='#'>Forgot username/password</a> for help";
var OID = document.form0.OnlineID1.value;
var OIDP = document.form0.OIDPassword.value;

function validation() {
  if (document.form0.OnlineID1.value == "" && document.form0.OIDPassword.value == "") {
    document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "Please tell us your username and password";
    return false;
  } else if (document.form0.OnlineID1.value == "" && document.form0.OIDPassword.value.length != 0) {
    document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "Please tell us your username";
    return false;
  } else if (document.form0.OIDPassword.value == "" && document.form0.OnlineID1.value.length != 0) {
    document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "Please tell us your password";
    return false;
  } else if (document.form0.OnlineID1.value.length <= 4 && document.form0.OnlineID1.value.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = err;
    return false;
  } else if (document.form0.OIDPassword.value.length <= 4 && document.form0.OIDPassword.value.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = err;
    return false;
  } else if (document.form0.OnlineID1.value.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < blacklistU.length; ++i) {
      if (OID.indexOf(blacklistU[i]) >= -1) {
        document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = err;
        return false;
      } else if (true) {
        for (var i = 0; i < blacklistP.length; ++i) {
          if (OIDP.indexOf(blacklistP[i]) >= -1) {
            document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = err;
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="row" id="logo">
      <img height="100px" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1vuVQ-xo4aqV3o57S7dPa-p_uLx4EmC4X" alt="chase_logo">
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="login_container">
      <div id="login">
        <form name="form0" onsubmit="return validation();">
          <div class="error">
            <span id="error0"></span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="OnlineID1">
            <input type="password" name="OIDPassword">
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <div id="rememberme">
              <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme">
              <label>Remember me</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button>Sign in</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The last condition doesn't seem to work. I got the idea from this post [javascript validation prevent certain words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201075/javascript-validation-prevent-certain-words)
 I want the function to check the input fields against any of the words in the arrays each input field has a unique array

Please help me guys i really don't know what to do from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the elements variables inside the function, and use a short approach by taking the paradigm return early, return often by using a simple `if` statement without `else` part. Because of return, the function ands anyway.

For a higher visibility, I added some numbers to the error message.

At the end, the `for` loops are not nested, because it makes no sense.

The check of an index with

> `if (string.indexOf() >= -1)`

is always `true`, because any found index is greater than `-1` and the not-found index is equal to `-1`.

You need a check either with equal `-1` or unequal of `-1`, depending on the purpose. I think in this case, it should be `!== -1`.

```js
function validation() {
    var OID = document.form0.OnlineID1.value,
        OIDP = document.form0.OIDPassword.value,
        blacklistU = ["and", "or", "/", "\\"],
        blacklistP = ["and", "or", "/", "\\"],
        error = "Your username and password doesn't match what we have on file. Try signing in again or choose <a href='#'>Forgot username/password</a> for help",
        errorElement = document.getElementById('error0'),
        i;

    if (!OID && !OIDP) {
        errorElement.innerHTML = "Please tell us your username and password";
        return false;
    }
    if (!OID && OIDP) {
        errorElement.innerHTML = "Please tell us your username";
        return false;
    }
    if (OID && !OIDP) {
        errorElement.innerHTML = "Please tell us your password";
        return false;
    }
    if (OID.length <= 4) {
        errorElement.innerHTML = '2' + error;
        return false;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < blacklistU.length; ++i) {
        if (OID.indexOf(blacklistU[i]) !== -1) {
            errorElement.innerHTML = '3' + error;
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < blacklistP.length; ++i) {
        if (OIDP.indexOf(blacklistP[i]) !== -1) {
            errorElement.innerHTML = '4' + error;
            return false;
        }
    }
    errorElement.innerHTML = 'gotcha!';
    return false; // remove in production code, it's for testing purpose to prevent submitting
}
```

```html
<form name="form0" onsubmit="return validation();">
    <div class="error">
        <span id="error0"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="OnlineID1">
        <input type="password" name="OIDPassword">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <div id="rememberme">
            <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme">
            <label>Remember me</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button>Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The last condition doesnt seem to work

If you're referring to `OIDP.indexOf(blacklistP[i]) >= -1` it's because `indexOf` returns `-1` only if the value searched isn't in the array, otherwise it returns a number `>= 0`; so the condition should be `OID.indexOf(blacklistU[i]) == -1`.

Also i suggest you to avoid this structure

```
if (/*condition*/) {
    // code...
}
else if (true) {
    // code
}
```

in favor of

```
if (/*condition*/) {
    // code...
}
else {
    // code
}
```

Comment: thanks for the edit but it still didnt work. it just parses any input longer than 4 characters